# Go - get parent struct

Tags: go, structure

I'd like to know how to retrieve the parent struct of an instance.
I have no idea how to implement this.

For instance:

```
type Hood struct {
    name string
    houses  []House
}

type House struct {
    name   string
    people int16
}

func (h *Hood) addHouse(house House) []House {
    h.houses = append(h.houses, house)
    return h.houses
}

func (house *House) GetHood() Hood {
    //Get hood where the house is situated
    return ...?
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should retain a pointer to the hood.

```
type House struct {
    hood   *Hood
    name   string
    people int16
}
```

and when you append the house

```
func (h *Hood) addHouse(house House) []House {
    house.hood = h
    h.houses = append(h.houses, house)
    return h.houses
}
```

then you can easily change the `GetHood`, although a getter may not be required at that point.

```
func (house *House) GetHood() Hood {
    return *house.hood
}
```

Comment: Ok thx for the idea. Nevertheless, syntax error i guess, it doesnt work. `cannot use house.hood (type *Hood) as type Hood in return argument`

Comment: @eouti Yes, it should be `return *house.hood`. See http://play.golang.org/p/bJO-VPweHf

Comment: i found another way is to declare the variable within the sub folder, and pass in the parent object to the sub directory function that set the variable.
example: ```var app *buffalo.App
func SetApp(t_app *buffalo.App) {
 app = t_app
}
```