# Get outer/parent struct name

Tags: go

I'm facing a Golang begginers problem, and I don't know how to solve it correctly. Could you please help me?

**Info:** Even though this is against the concept of Go (not trying to be an OOP language) I'd like to discuss some solutions still.

I'd like to know the outer/parent struct name within the receiver/child. Please have a look at the following code (playground: https://play.golang.org/p/h6dARJQwidS )

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Parent struct {
    Id uint32
}

func (p *Parent) GetStructName() string {
    return reflect.TypeOf(p).Elem().Name()
}


type Child struct {
    Parent
}


func main() {
    myChild := Child{}
    fmt.Println(myChild.GetStructName()) // Gives "Parent" instead of "Child". How to get "Child"?
}
```

It displays "Parent", although the struct is a "Child". Can anyone tell me how to get the correct struct name? I've seen one 'solution' in another stackoverflow topic that works 'correctly' ([Go - get parent struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27918208/go-get-parent-struct)), but I don't think this is a good solution.

Comment: Go does not have inheritance. Trying to pretend it does is only going to make things difficult. Rework your solution to make use of the available methods of composition instead.

Comment: @JimB Ok. I'll dig into it. From your perspective: Can composition solve this problem or do I need to re-think the structure completely?

Comment: You’re trying to solve your problem with inheritance. I’m sure there’s alterntive ways to solve your problem (there are lots of non-OOP languages), but you’re only describing your proposed solution, rather than an actual problem statement.

Answer (score 4):

`GetStructName` is a method of the type `Parent` not `Child`, also Golang does not have inheritance, instead there is struct embedding (also there is interface embedding), which is sort of like inheritance, but with a key difference:

> When we embed a type, the methods of that type become methods of the outer type, but when they are invoked the receiver of the method is the inner type, not the outer one.

This basically means that when you call `GetStructName`, the receiver of the method is `Parent` (the inner or embedded type), and not `Child`.

This is fundamentally different from the typical class inheritance, and it explains the behaviour you're seeing.

It's well documented [here](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding).

Comment: Ok - thank you. I think I want to go with the head through the wall when trying to use OOP in Go. But it still feels "right" to do it though :-)

Answer (score 4):

For completeness I wanted to share my solution to it (Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/tUhlz_o8Z7V).

As described in my initial question, the idea is from [Go - get parent struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27918208/go-get-parent-struct) .

It's also related to a Go2 request that I've seen here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/28254

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "reflect"
)

// we need an interface so methods are being embedded automatically
type IParent interface {
    Init(IParent)   IParent
}

// internal private fields, non-visible from the outside
type Parent struct {
    _IsInitialized  bool
    _Self           IParent
}

// init the struct, set "_Self" to it's caller
func (p *Parent) Init(o IParent) IParent {
    p._Self = o
    p._IsInitialized = true
    return o
}

// This method uses "_Self" to determine what it actually is
func (p *Parent) GetStructName() string {
    if !p._IsInitialized {
        log.Fatal("Struct not initialized. You may call 'myVar.Init(&myVar)' to initialize it.")
    }
    return reflect.TypeOf(p._Self).Elem().Name()
}

// Below childs have "Init()" from Parent, so they implement IParent automatically
// No need to duplicate any methods here anymore
type Child1 struct {
    Parent
}

type Child2 struct {
    Parent
}

type Child3 struct {
    Parent
}

type Child4 struct {
    Parent
}

func main() {
    myChild1 := Child1{}
    myChild1.Init(&myChild1) // Init object (set _Self on struct)
    fmt.Println(myChild1.GetStructName()) // Gives "Child1"

    myChild2 := Child2{}
    myChild2.Init(&myChild2) // Init object (set _Self on struct)
    fmt.Println(myChild2.GetStructName()) // Gives "Child2"

    myChild3 := Child3{}
    myChild3.Init(&myChild3) // Init object (set _Self on struct)
    fmt.Println(myChild3.GetStructName()) // Gives "Child3"

    myChild4 := Child4{}
    fmt.Println(myChild4.GetStructName()) // Fatal error
}

// Footnotes:
//---
//
//  This attempt tries to solve a go 'inheritance' problem although go is *NOT* meant to be an OOP language. It was a funny experiment still :-)
//  License: open domain, no attribution
//  https://www.xsigndll.com
//
//---
```

Answer (score -2):

While Daniel's answer above answers the "why" of it, you can still "sorta" get the behaviour you are probably looking for via (a slightly ugly):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type NamedReturningType interface {
    GetStructName() string
}

type Parent struct {
    Id uint32
}

func (p *Parent) GetStructName() string {
    return reflect.TypeOf(p).Elem().Name()
}


type Child struct {
    Parent
}

func (c *Child) GetStructName() string {
    return reflect.TypeOf(c).Elem().Name()
}

func main() {

    myChild := Child{}
    fmt.Println(myChild.GetStructName())

    myParent := Parent{}
    fmt.Println(myParent.GetStructName())
}
```

(playground: https://play.golang.org/p/qEtoEulFSPy )

EDIT: Added an interface that these types can implement so as to make the code more generic.

Comment: That was one of my "solutions" as well, but this one implied writing the same method into every child over and over again. I may have to understand the concept of compostion better and see if I can rework the code towards the go-concept.

Comment: I added an interface to the above code to make it a bit generic so that you can now use the interface in functions that  must implement this name returning function. Nevertheless, like you said, composition would be the way to go.